# Data Factory Copy Activity met an internal service error

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have an ADF pipeline that copies 34 tables from an on premise Oracle database to an Azure data lake store; 32 of these copy just fine on a daily basis, the other 2 consistenly fail with...

```
Copy activity met an internal service error. 
For more information, provide this message to customer support. ErrorCode: 8601 GatewayNodeName=XXXXXXXX,
ErrorCode=SystemErrorOdbcWrapperError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Unknown error from wrapper.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,
''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Runtime.ValueException,Message=[DataSource.Error] The ODBC driver returned an invalid value.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Wrapper,'.
```

The activity JSON is templated so is identical for all 34 activities. I can run the oracleReaderQuery in Oracle SQL Developer using the same connection details and credentials and get results.

Searches for this have shown 1 unanswered question on here (StackOverflow) and another Microsoft with a response that says "We will get back to you ASAP when we have new updates"....but there are no updates.

It seems I am not the only one having this issue; has anyone found a solution?

I have tried to do a one off copy in ADF but get the same result; I have tried copying the table to blob storage and get the same result.

Can anyone help me try to fathom what is wrong with this please?

The activity JSON is as follows...

```
    {
    "type": "Copy",
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "OracleSource",
            "oracleReaderQuery": "SELECT stuff FROM <source table>"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink",
            "writeBatchSize": 0,
            "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
        }
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "<source table dataset>"
        },
        {
            "name": "<scheduling dependency dataset>"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "<destination dataset>"
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "02:00:00",
        "concurrency": 1,
        "retry": 3,
        "longRetry": 2,
        "longRetryInterval": "03:00:00",
        "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst"
    },
    "scheduler": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "name": "Copy Activity 34",
    "description": "copy activity"
}
```

As I said though, this is identical, apart from the table it is accessing, to the 32 activities that work perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you post the structure / datatype of the columns for the table that is consistently failing ? It is possible that it might contain a data type that is NOT fully supported by the copy activity. For Example there are few workarounds for Geo Location Type and such

Answer (score -1):

What's the data type of stuff in your table?

Comment: `SELECT stuff FROM <source table>` is just representative of the oracleReaderQuery, the actual query selects 16 columns - 5xDate, 3xNumber, and 8xVARCHAR2 ranging from 1 to 35 characters in length. If I set the query to just read the first 30 records it is fine, but I need to read the whole table and I have no idea how to determine why it won't read the table when it runs fine in SQL Developer

Comment: It's more efficient for us to help you out, if you can create a ticket on Azure portal about the problem.